# React PDF not rendering PDF in IOS 15.5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview, react-pdf

I am using `react-pdf` to render a pdf in a react application which is then rendered via `WebView` in `ios` and `android`.

The pdf render works in `android`.

In `ios`, I am getting this error `Total canvas memory use exceeds the maximum limit (224 MB).`

```js
           <Document
                file={pdfBlob}
                onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
                renderMode="canvas"
                loading={<AppLoader />}
              >
                <Page
                  object-fit="fill"
                  pageNumber={currentPage}
                  width={isMobile && 350}
                  loading={<AppLoader />}
                  onRenderSuccess={() => {
                    setPdfRenderLoading(false);
                  }}
                  renderTextLayer={false}
                />
                <IconWrapper isMobile={isMobile}>
                  <IconButton
                    disabled={!canGoToPrev()}
                    colorScheme="blue"
                    aria-label="go-previous"
                    icon={<ChevronLeftIcon fontSize={fontSizes.md} />}
                    backgroundColor={appColors.brandGrey['50']}
                    color={appColors.brandGrey['900']}
                    mr={2}
                    onClick={handlePrevPage}
                  />
                  <AppText title={`${currentPage} of ${totalPages}`} />
                  <IconButton
                    disabled={!canGoToNext()}
                    colorScheme="blue"
                    aria-label="go-next"
                    icon={<ChevronRightIcon fontSize={fontSizes.md} />}
                    backgroundColor={appColors.brandGrey['50']}
                    color={appColors.brandGrey['900']}
                    ml={2}
                    onClick={handleNextPage}
                  />
                </IconWrapper>
              </Document>
```

I am fetching the pdf from `s3` and storing it as a `blob` to prevent fetching everytime the page rerenders

My dependencies

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.1.7",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.8",
    "@emotion/react": "^11",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11",
    "@fontsource/nunito": "^4.5.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chakra-react-select": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^6",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
    "react-query": "^3.38.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "use-debounce": "^8.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "zustand": "^4.0.0-rc.1"
  }
```

The entire block is displayed inside a webview using `react-native-webview`

The pdf starts to render, but get stucks and then the canvas error pops up, is there a fix for this in `react-pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOS prevents painting the canvas for such memory.`"Total canvas memory use exceeds the maximum limit (384 MB)."` Hence React PDF is unable to paint the image.

A quick fix would be to change `renderMode` to `svg` which just renders the SVG.

SVG takes a bit more time to load than the Canvas. As the Canvas can be viewed to the user and then be painted / rendered, Whereas the SVG is completely rendered before the user can view.

This can be a deal breaker for large PDFs or PDFs with image rich content as rendering SVGs will take a longer time to render

```js
           <Document
                file={pdfBlob}
                onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
                renderMode="svg" // Changed
                loading={<AppLoader />}
              >
                <Page
                  object-fit="fill"
                  pageNumber={currentPage}
                  width={isMobile && 350}
                  loading={<AppLoader />}
                  onRenderSuccess={() => {
                    setPdfRenderLoading(false);
                  }}
                  renderTextLayer={false}
                />
                <IconWrapper isMobile={isMobile}>
                  <IconButton
                    disabled={!canGoToPrev()}
                    colorScheme="blue"
                    aria-label="go-previous"
                    icon={<ChevronLeftIcon fontSize={fontSizes.md} />}
                    backgroundColor={appColors.brandGrey['50']}
                    color={appColors.brandGrey['900']}
                    mr={2}
                    onClick={handlePrevPage}
                  />
                  <AppText title={`${currentPage} of ${totalPages}`} />
                  <IconButton
                    disabled={!canGoToNext()}
                    colorScheme="blue"
                    aria-label="go-next"
                    icon={<ChevronRightIcon fontSize={fontSizes.md} />}
                    backgroundColor={appColors.brandGrey['50']}
                    color={appColors.brandGrey['900']}
                    ml={2}
                    onClick={handleNextPage}
                  />
                </IconWrapper>
              </Document>
```

Comment: I changed renderMode to renderMode="svg", but I got a white blank screen in iOS. Before that, I got a canvas error on iOS. Any opinion?

Comment: renderMode="svg" and also downgrade of react-pdf to 5.2.0 helped.